# Tracking info view is not visible in google analytics dashboard

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have created an account in google analytics and not able to find the tracking info column within the properties section. [image]

How to find the tracking ID?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have created an app + web property that is in beta and follows a completely different paradigm from Analytics that we know, if you want that you have to use the not app + web web property but web.